# Mobile Version Rendered By A Different PHP File Preserving Friendly URL's

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have a website about books.
Currently, it already has some URL Rewrite rules on my .htaccess file, so that such URL's are more friendly:

http://www.example.com/book.php?book=xxx  -> http://www.example.com/book/xxx.html

The rule for that:

RewriteRule ^book/([^/]+).html$ book.php?book=$1 [QSA,L]

Now I am developing a mobile version exclusevely to the book section, that means that the index.php and all other pages remain the same. So I would like to have URL's like this (when the user agent is detected as of a mobile gadget):

http://www.example.com/mobile/m_book.php?book=xxx -> http://m.example.com/book/xxx.html

My current solution (**that is not working**), rewrites the url correctly, but then the server does not find the PHP to render the page and I receive a "Server not found" on the browser.
The PHP file to render regular book page is book.php, but the PHP file responsible to render only to mobile devices is in a subfolder and can be found by: mobile/m_book.php

```
RewriteEngine On

#To detect mobile browsers
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ (ce|phone)|xda|xiino [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\ |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |\/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) [NC]
#To avoid loops
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.example\.com$ [NC]
#First Rewrite Rule
RewriteRule ^book/([^/]+)\.html$ http://m.example.com/m_book.php?book=$1 [QSA,L,R]

#Only the mobile request should be rendered by mobile/m_book.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^book/([^/]+)\.html$ mobile/m_book.php?book=$1 [QSA,L,R]

#Otherwise (the already predefined rule)
RewriteRule ^book/([^/]+)\.html$ book.php?book=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**What is wrong with this piece of code?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Server not found" is strange, I'd expect "Page not found". You are using an external redirect [R] to http://m.example.com/m_book.php?book=$1 when the user agent is a mobile browser. If I understand you correctly, the page /m_book.php doesn't exist, just /book.php as well as /mobile/m_book.php do exist.

So, after you redirect to http://m.example.com/m_book.php?book=$1, no other rules applies, that's your final (and non-existing) page. Shouldn't you rather use

```
#First Rewrite Rule
RewriteRule ^book/([^/]+)\.html$ http://m.example.com/mobile/m_book.php?book=$1 [QSA,L,R]
```

which hits the correct page and should work but looks ugly in the browser.

Or, if you want the URL to look nice

```
#First Rewrite Rule
RewriteRule ^book/([^/]+)\.html$ http://m.example.com/book/$1.html [QSA,L,R]
```

which redirects, but then your next rule

```
#Only the mobile request should be rendered by mobile/m_book.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^book/([^/]+)\.html$ mobile/m_book.php?book=$1 [QSA,L,R]
```

does have the correct condition as well as matching rule and does what is expected.

This is theory, I haven't tested it. And btw, I don't think you need the [QSA] flag which causes the query strings to be combined because you effectively exclude query strings.

Comment: I still got "Server not found"... 
It correctly redirects to http://m.example.com/book/name-of-book.html but then "Server not found" appears! =/

Comment: Just to be sure: if you call the subdomain directly, the page renders correctly?

Comment: Yes. When I access example.com/mobile/m_book.php it renders correctly.
But m.example.com/mobile/m_book.php  does not work

Comment: Again, does the SUBdomain render correctly? If you call m.example.com, it should work, otherwise it is not a *redirect* issue but a domain issue. Is the subdomain m pointing to your webspace correctly?

Comment: Then I think it is a subdomain problem. When I call m.example.com it does not work.

Comment: Absolutely. Don't know where and how you are developing and deploying, but that's the first thing you should make sure. As soon as m.example.... works, the other stuff will work as well.

Comment: OK. I'm gonna check this out with the hosting service and let you know. Thx.

Comment: Now the m.example.com works but m.example.com/book/xxx.html gives me a Error 404 Object not found! 
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Comment: Does the page you rediret *to* work? I.e. does m.example.com/mobile/m_book.php?book=xxx work?

Comment: It wwas a problem with the host! Thank ya! Here's your 50 points!

Comment: Good to know it works. And thanks for rewarding my little effort in this - very generous!